# Issue with Access PHP array in display module

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I am passing few parameters via ajax to custom module `(fgs_api.module)` and in returns getting JSON data `($results->data)`. I want to use/get that variable `($results->data)` in `node--xyz.tpl.php` content template. How can I use that variable in `node--xyz.tpl.php`. I am doing in drupal 7.

In module `fgs_api.module`

```
function fgs_api_data_execute($parameter1, $parameter2)
{   
    if(!is_null($parameter1) && !is_null($parameter2))
    {
        // my custom code which is working
         $results = $api->{'getSpecialOfferHomes'}(intval($parameter1), intval($parameter2)); 

        if($results->success)
        {
            $return = fgs_api_format_return(false, $results->data);
        }else{
            $return = fgs_api_format_return(true, $results->message);
        }
    }else{
        $return = fgs_api_format_return(true, 'Incorrect parameters');
    }
    return $return;
}
```

In Js

```
  var url = '/fgs_api_data_execute/' + parameter1 + '/' + parameter2;    
                console.log(url);

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {   
                        if (result.data) {
                             console.log(result['data']);  // use this data in Module           
                        }else {
                           console.log("error");
                        }
                    },
```

How can I use/pass return data variable from custom module to `node--xyz.tpl.php`?

Comment: Maybe dumb question but as I seem to not understand what's going on I'll ask anyway: You have a function in your theme and want to execute it in your module? What's happening when you just call the function in the module? And what's that Ajax about? Can you please edit your question to add clarification or a step by step to reproduce this issue? Many thanks 

Comment: @leymannx I have updated dumb question. AJAX call is for passing few parameters while click.  I may not following drupal best practices. I have custom module. I am getting data as results but can't access data in node template.

Comment: You are trying to use clientside data (from javascript) in your serverside template (Twig / PHP), so you clearly do not understand what you are doing. I'd say this question does not belong here and you should do some tutorials about how PHP and AJAX work.